# How do I decide what car charger I need to buy?

Tags: battery, charging, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, car-dock

I am with Nexus 5 and finding it difficult to decide on what car charger or car dock with charger I need to buy.

As there is no accessories from parent company (LG or Google) I not sure what charger I need to buy.

On the whole how one has to decide what third party car charger will suit android devices?

Comment: any car adapter with a reputable brand that has a USB port and can supply 1.5A or greater is fine. I know Sony, Samsung and HTC sells those accesories.

Comment: OK. Can you suggest me one?

Comment: here's one from [samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ECA-U21CBEBXAR). But really, any brand name car charger is fine. Just take into account its power supply and has a USB port.